# how to resume failed downloads on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, setup

i am trying to download cygwin inorder to try out **android ndk development** on windows.
The problem is i have a slow internet connection and it requires its own online installer yet the download keeps getting interupted.
**Question**
How can i resume cygwin downloads without having to start from the beginning

Comment: whyare you using Cygwin? Isn't NDK available for Windows too?

Comment: cygwin is needed for compiling by the ndk build system under windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter in the same local download directory you did before. Every time you stop and start it should pick up automatically where it left off.

If you need help follow this thread http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2001-11/msg01930.html

Comment: its suprisingly starting from the beginning each time, Meaning that the 600 mb i already downloaded is totally wasted. :(

Comment: what mirror are you using?

Comment: cygwin.parentingamerica.com I am going to try an html spider to scan their site and download anything it can.

Comment: There are three other Canadian mirror sites you could try   mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca  , mirror.cpsc.ucalgary.ca and cygwin.skazkaforyou.com It could be that the link between the http you were using and the main ftp is having issues.

Comment: I'm pretty annoyed by cygwin's setup too -- it's not your internet connection, I have 35/35 fiber with constant access and it's been stuck at the same spot for over a day.  You'd think it would be able to automatically switch mirrors if one crapped out, etc. -- but no. -- and if you select more than one, it thinks you want to download it all twice! DX

Comment: Also (especially when switching mirrors, but even if not) it definitely does not pick up where it left off.

Comment: Same problem as @DrDeo - Not sure what you mean "enter in the same local download directory" as I just go with the defaults every time and I'm sure they aren't changing on their own.  It does *not* just "pick up automatically where it left off". I'm just glad I decided to wait until I was back at my desk to retry, otherwise my data plan would have taken a huge hit.